# Not able to set a column as timestamp or datetime datatype in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, timestamp, workbench

Whenever I set a column with timestamp or datetime it automatically changes to varchar.
I'm using Mysql server ver 5.7.18
MySQL workbench ver 6.3.9

Comment: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You try to alter a column or create a new one? Error Messages?

Comment: @BitAccesser during creation